# Select2 call function with select2-selecting in append data

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 for the selection of options in a form.

[capture-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVHGb.png)

The form is dynamic, so new lines are added when I click on the add button.

[capture-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEFkQ.png)

The problem I have is that the function works only on the initial line, and not on the secondary lines.

```
$('.select2').on("select2-selecting", function(e) { 
       alert(“HELLO”);
});
```

Any ideas? regards

Comment: Please, post a complete example, or at least the dynamic generated HTML form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add/re-enable the event handling everytime new select2 element is added to DOM.

Wrap it in a function and call it after you add row.

```
function initSelectEvent(){
    // reset the previous event handlers on existing selects
    $('.select2').off("select2-selecting") 
    // enable again including the newly added
    $('.select2').on("select2-selecting", function(e) { 
        // your code to handle selected item
   });
}

/// in your code that adds the new row

...
initSelectEvent()
```